# Xcode Can't remove file from Project Navigator that was removed from Github Repository

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have a file that I removed from the GitHub interface and then merged the new commit by `recursive` strategy. While the file is gone from my directory and GitHub repo, the file remains within my Project navigator and I am unable to delete it. It is now in red font and can't be removed. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All that was needed was to remove the target from the file. Once that was unchecked I was able to remove the file.